# select specific cells and place data in other cells excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a function from which i can select specific cells and place them in the other columns.
For example, I have data in the following form:

```
- Food Processor
- 756
- 890
- Washing Machine
- 290
- 900
- Mixer
- 123
- 893
```

Now, i want the data in the following form in separate columns:

```
- Food Processor
- Washing Machine   
- Mixer
```

in one column

And the prices in two separate columns.

How do i do that?
Thank you!

Comment: Why not record a macro with all the necessary movements? That's sometimes much easier than trying to write a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you data there was in A1:A9 and you needed every 3rd row in column B then in B1
=OFFSET($A$1,3*(ROW()-1),0)
and copy down
will give you the 3 records you want from A1,A4,A7 in B1, B2, B3

Comment: No Probs. It works by offsetting A1 by 3 cells for every row the formula is copied down, ie in B2 it offsets A1 by 3*(2-1) = 3 cells, in B3 it offsets A1 by 3*(3-1) = 6 cells etc. Please close the question out if it helped :)